# Unwanted space between two columns of form in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create tooltip for input box similar to this.[image]

But when I try in my code there is too much space left in between input box and tooltip as shown in below image. I am using two different columns for input box and tooltip. 
[image]

My Code for username & tooltip row is as follows:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-4">
  <form action="<?php echo base_url('loginclient/verify'); ?>" method="post" name="login_form" onsubmit=" return validateForm()">
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="username" autofocus="autofocus" pattern="([^ ]){6,}" title="Minimum length is 6, without any space." required="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1" style="background-color:pink">
  <a class="pull-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Enter your username">?</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If any of answer worked for you, mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap Grid system having default padding for column class so use inline css to overhead the padding like

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1" style="background-color:pink; padding:0px !important;">
```

Comment: thank you for your replay. Yes tooltip goes to left , but there is still some space. Is there any way such that tooltip will touch the input box from right?

Answer (score 0):

the parent div of form has a padding-right (and also padding-left) of 15px

you can apply a style to it to correct it:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-4" style="padding-right:0;">
  <form action="<?php echo base_url('loginclient/verify'); ?>" method="post" name="login_form" onsubmit=" return validateForm()">
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="username" autofocus="autofocus" pattern="([^ ]){6,}" title="Minimum length is 6, without any space." required="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1" style="background-color:pink">
  <a class="pull-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Enter your username">?</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's your feedback about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows.

Best way is to use `.input-group-addon`

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .input-group {
    position: static;
  }
  .input-group-addon {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0;
  }
  .input-group .form-control {
    border-radius: 4px!important;
  }
</style>

<div class=container>
  <div class="input-group" style="width:250px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right"></span></span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow html structure like this. This is the best way use tooltip with text box.

```css
.input {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 100px;
}
.qtooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top:5px;
  right:75px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="<?php echo base_url('loginclient/verify'); ?>" method="post" name="login_form" onsubmit=" return validateForm()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class=" input">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="username" autofocus="autofocus" pattern="([^ ]){6,}" title="Minimum length is 6, without any space." required="" />
      <div class="qtooltip">
        <a class="pull-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Enter your username">?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```